# Determining double tap with winapi

Tags: c++, winapi, touch

I'm using WinAPI's WM_TOUCH event to detect taps. It works great so far, but I'm unsure of the "right way" on how to detect double- or triple-taps.

I am thinking something like, I record the time the last WM_TOUCH event was recorded. When I receive another WM_TOUCH event, I get the difference in milliseconds since the last WM_TOUCH event, and if it's within an acceptable time, then I can treat it as a double-tap. It follows the same logic for triple taps.

I have not seen anything on MSDN for using WM_TOUCH for double- or triple-taps, only multi-touches. Is there some easier way to detect a double- or triple-tap, or am I supposed to roll my own like above?

Comment: That's basically, how you'd do it. You may wish to take the double-click area into account. Sample code and explanations at [Implementing higher-order clicks](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041018-00/?p=37543). In case you still need the lower-order clicks/taps, you will have to install a timer (e.g. a double-click timeout timer on the first click/tap; when it expires prior to the next click/tap, you have a single-click/tap).